# C# - Access form from another project/solution in different dot-net targetting

Tags: c#

I have two projects called projectA and ProjectB

ProjectA properties(dotnet4, X64)
ProjectB properties(Dotnet 3.5, X86)

What I want to do is that how can access projectB.from1 from projectA

Note: I have tested both projects independently they have worked fine.
And also I have tested by adding projectB into ProjectA as existing project, the main program runs fine but the projectB.form1 have an error

I have tried as follows by using the name space of imported projectB

```
  MainForm vsf = new MainForm();
            vsf.Show();
```

The error message is:
[image]

Comment: What in the world is generating that message box? Did you give it that title? There is no way that any of the Microsoft provided code would be generating a message box with that title. Anyway, this will not work---you cannot mix code with different bitness in a single process. One of those projects is compiled for 64-bit, while the other is compiled for 32-bit. You need to recompile one of them.

Comment: yes 'that title', I was just wondering :) - if they're pure .NET (no native code) then build with 'Any CPU' (or at least make it the same). If you do have e.g. C++ libs inside then it's more complex, and you need to start from that and work your way up (end goal is as commented already, either x86 or x64).

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference whether there is native or managed code involved. In both cases, you need to recompile all projects to target the same architecture.

Comment: @CodyGray you didn't understand the point (and took that out of context) - we agree on that (they need to target the same) - but the process is very different - and for managed only is usually very simple to sort things out - for native dependencies that could mean lot more trouble and the process is different. I didn't want to neat-pick about it, but to help the OP as that's the next step.

Comment: @nsg I don't really understand how the process is any different or more complicated. You just recompile the binaries in both cases. I'm not trying to take anything out of context, I apologize. I just don't understand where the trouble is.

Answer (score 1):

That's looks like a issue with target framework version mismatch with your `ProjectB`. Change the target framework of `ProjectB` to `dotnet4` as well before referencing it in `ProjectA`. Also, there is a mismatch in the runtime architecture. That is, one running in `X64` and another in `X86`. Make sure both the project is compatible.

Comment: I have also tried before as you have said and it doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @ensberiyu, Why? you need to change the framework version as well as architecture of your project. Then re-compile and add the reference. It should work fine.

Comment: I have tried that ProjectB is working with Dot-net 3.5 and X86 architecture only since its project and libraries are the member of that dot-net.